# Error encountered during contract execution - Out of gas

Tags: contract-deployment, out-of-gas

I try to create a smart contract (Simple TokenERC20) with sendRawTransaction().

```
    var firstMainadress = '0x3c7B83E0Fa6f19B1B61e80A73630cB5Db48b700C';
    var secondAdress = '0x38ebbB608fbb40fca07e0EcBAc89e20520BD33f1';
    var privateKey = new Buffer('xxxprivateKeyThatIcantShowHere...','hex')
    var data =  this.byteCode;
    var nonce = this.web3.toHex(this.web3.eth.getTransactionCount(firstMainadress));
    var gasPrice = this.web3.toHex(1000000000);
    var gasLimitHex = this.web3.toHex(1253608);
    var rawTx = { 'data': data, 'nonce': nonce, 'gasPrice': gasPrice, 'gasLimit': gasLimitHex, 'from': firstMainadress};
    var tx = new Tx(rawTx);
    tx.sign(privateKey);
    var serializedTx = '0x'+tx.serialize().toString('hex')
    this.web3.eth.sendRawTransaction(serializedTx, function(err, txHash){
      console.log(err, txHash);
      this.deployedContract = txHash;

    })
```

the txHash is not null, and when i put it on etherscan, i see the bellow error :

[image: the transaction who create the contract exist but he fail in the end !]

Can someone help me to found why i have this error message : 
Warning! Error encountered during contract execution [Out of gas]

Thnaks a lot for your help :)

Comment: Do you have a link to the etherscan transaction? If your contract has a bug it can cause to consume all the remaining gas.

Comment: From the link to your transaction in ropsten https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0x0a4c81c6aa72a6e2b6af441ec887ee2b0d3a808d2448a7d528a178f259af53f1 it seems you missed to append a '0x' in front of your bytecode. If you look at the input data it is `0x36303630..` and most contracts created with solidity is `0x6060..`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough rep to comment... :/ But, I had a very similar issue and @Ismael 's above answer was spot on! I forgot to prepend my byte code with 0x, and have since added this small validation:

```
if (tokenSource.byteCode.slice(0,2) !== '0x') {
throw new ValidatorException('Issue with contract source file formatting, ensure starts with \'0x\'', {
  token
});
```

Many thanks again to Ismael above

> it seems you missed to append a '0x' in front of your bytecode.

Comment: If Ismael helped you, rate up his comment!